# HTML Button Link to Website from Text

Tags: html, button, hyperlink

I am trying to use an HTML button to link to a new website given a provided text field input.

I have choices like this:

```
Option: <br />
                One <input type="radio" value="Short"
                name="option" <br />: 
                Two <input type="radio" value="Long"
                name="option" <br />:
                Three <input type="radio" value="Zero"
                name="option" <br />:
```

And I want to have a button go to .../one if One is selected, .../two if Two is selected, etc...

```
<form> <input class="MyButton" type="button" value="Google"
         onclick=window.location.href='www.google.com' /> </form>
```

I know this is how I go to a specified link, but I want to go to a link based on my option choice, not a static choice. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Af first you have to fix your **HTML** Error. No input element has end tag.

Wrap one, two, three with span

```
Option: <br />
   <span>One</span> <input type="radio" value="Short" name="option" /> <br />
   <span>Two</span> <input type="radio" value="Long" name="option" /> <br />
   <span>Three</span> <input type="radio" value="Zero" name="option" /> <br />

<form> <input class="MyButton" type="button" value="Google" /> </form>
```

Then you can get your select value and set button `onclick` value

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("input[type='radio']").click(function(){
       var text = $(this).prev('span').text();
       $('form > input').attr('onclick',
            "javascript:window.location.href='https://www.google.com/" + text + "'");
   });

});
```

After that you click on `Google` button, you will redired to https://www.google.com/yourSelectValue

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript for this.

Make a function call when the button is clicked. something like this...

```
<input type="button" onclick="myfunction()"/>
```

and inside the function get the values from text input and use appropriate methods to go to the link.

Comment: How do I get the values from text input though?

Comment: @Logan just google it dude...its like this-    var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;

Answer (score 0):

I personally wouldn't use javascript for this, you can just use a normal button with the URL in the `formaction` attribute.

```
<form>
    <button formaction="http://stackexchange.com">Stackexchange</button>
</form>
```

The `form` tags are required.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-formaction